# publish php websocket server from private computer

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, server, ip

What I'm trying to do is PHP WebSocket server to run a chat application.
It worked for me on localhost but when I upload it to a domain with DNS, the javascript does not connect to the server.

server.php

```
<?php   
  require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
  require __DIR__ . '/So/Chat.php';

  use So\Chat;

  use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
  use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
  use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

                                                                    //What to write here?
  $server = IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(new WsServer(new Chat)) 8080,'192.168.1.12');
  $server->run();
?>
```

connection.js

```
    function Connection(username, chatWindowId) {
        this.username = username;
        this.chatwindow = document.getElementById(chatWindowId);

        this.open = false;

        this.socket = new WebSocket("ws://5.29.101.176:80");//And here?
        this.setupConnectionEvents();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post PHP code so that we can understand your problem better?

Comment: Is the IP of your server correct?

Comment: Yes, you think the problem is the ip?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library, but I'm willing to guess that `'5.29.101.176:80'` as a second parameter is not really correct since you can't really open a socket on a remote server using a locally running script (or can you?)

Comment: I don't know, It worked for me on localhost, I corrected the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $server = IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(new WsServer(new Chat)),80,'127.0.0.1'); 
  $server->run();
```

try this in server side

Comment: OK, And what to change in the js?

Comment: It says: WebSocket connection to 'ws://5.29.101.176/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Comment: Can you provide a little context for your answer?

Comment: you missed the port number in php code , can you try by correcting it?

Comment: also try with 0.0.0.0 as ip  in your server side code.

Comment: I didn't miss the port number in PHP code, it gives me an error when I put it